# Unable to configure Cloudant NoSQL DB Extension from Watson IoT Plaftorm dashboard

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, watson-iot

I'm trying to enable the Cloudant NoSQL DB extension to maintain all the data collected from the devices but the configuration is not working.

I select the interval, the time zone and the db name and I confirm the settings but a spinner starts and it never ends.

In first place, I had pop-ups blocked so I enabled them and recreated the Cloudant NoSQL DB service, but the issue is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a Private Window in your browser and do it there.  It seems to get all confused (I suspect with cookies) after a pop-up has been blocked the first time.

Comment: took me a lot longer when it was me couldn't get it working ;-).  Was a once off though, havn't had to do it since.

Comment: I still have the problem that every time I refresh the dashboard, I loose all the data collected. Is there a way to force Watson IoT Platform to write on the db?

Comment: But that is what setting up historical data does.  Go to your bluemix dashboard, launch cloudant.  Send in some data and see if it's writing to your iotp db for today (or month, depends on bucket interval).  I'd guess it is but the problem is dashboard ain't reading from the db.